# Do I need a transit visa to transfer terminals in Hong Kong

Tags: transit, hong-kong, airport-terminals

I am traveling from the USA (Texas) to India but I have two different tickets, i.e from Texas to Hong Kong and another ticket from Hong Kong to India (Delhi). I don’t have a transit visa.

At present I am in the Terminal 1 lounge area. I need to transit from Terminal 1 to 2.

- Do I need a transit visa?
- If so, is there any other way I could deal it without any trouble?

I don’t have any check-in baggage. I am an Indian citizen.

I wasn’t able to take the flight from HKG to India on Jet airways, which I booked in Texas while boarding from Texas to HKG  on American Airlines. So I booked another ticket online after reaching HKG.

- Does this create any trouble for me to transit from terminal 1 to 2?
- My specific question is do I need to book both tickets at the same time?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: The [Transfer/Transit Procedures](https://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/passenger/transfer-transit/all/transit_procedures.html) does not say anything about going through immigration.

Comment: Do you need to retrieve checked bags and recheck them?

Comment: Good point @phoog. The transit web page I found says nothing about checked bags, so I assume it is for the case in which any checked bags have been tagged through to the destination.

Comment: Have you seen the information about pre-arrival registration for Indian nationals?  It is at http://www.discoverhongkong.com/in/plan-your-trip/traveller-info/immigration-and-customs/visa-information.jsp

Answer (score 2):

> **Do I need to have the transit visa?**

[No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Hong_Kong#Transit_visa_required) according to Wikipedia.

The fact that AA let you board a flight terminating in HKG is also a reasonable indication that your travel documents are sufficient to enter or transit HK.

According to the [HK government](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html)

> Indian nationals are required to apply for and successfully complete pre-arrival registration (PAR) online before they can visit the HKSAR visa free.

It is unclear to me whether this applies to transits from T1 to T2 (some nationalities need an entry visa just to transit) but they list details of contacts you could consult.

---

> **Do I need to book both the tickets at the same time?**

You'll either get sent back to the US at AA's expense or will transit OK. As you are sitting in HKG there is no way for you to go back in time to book both legs at the same time or to arrange a transit visa. negative answers to these questions are unlikely to be of any help to you. You have to deal with the situation you are presently in, not work out what you should have done in the past.

---

> **If [a transit visa is required], is there any other way I could deal it with out any trouble?**

No.

If you need a visa and don't have one, trouble is inevitable.

---

I suggest you make your way to T2 and see what happens or in T1 request assistance from the representatives of the airline you booked through to Delhi.

Comment: All arrival and transit passengers will go to T1 only, T2 is used for departure, and there's no boarding gates in T2

Answer (score 0):

@phoog
I don’t have any check-in baggage
@Patricia  Shanahan 
I am an Indian citizen
My doubt is do I need to book both the tickets at the same time. Actually I wasn’t able to take the flight from HKG—>India (jet airways) which I booked in Texas while boarding from Texas to HKG (American Airlines). So I booked another ticket online after reaching HKG. Does this create any trouble for me to transit from terminal 1 to 2.

My specific question is do I need to book both the tickets at the same time?

Comment: Hi Damy, if this is your question,please goto [contact](https://travel.stackexchange.com/contact) and ask to merge your accounts, that way you will be able to edit your question. Please do not add supplements or comments as answer.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick.  Thank you for the detailed inputs.                                                              At the moment I check-in online and got an e-boarding pass. I hope I don’t have to transit to terminal 2. Waiting for transfer desk(jet airways) to open and approach them and check if any issue.

Comment: @Damy You can Transfer to T2 without Clearing immigration

Comment: @Crazydre Actually, you can't get to T2 from T1 without clearing immigration. The T2 airside area is for departure only.

Comment: @K.T.L.Lo There must be a Transfer bus or corridor. The Timatic database used by airlines lists countries where transfer between terminals requires a visa, and Hong Kong is not one of them

Comment: @Crazydre Landside corridor from T1 to/from T2, airside train from T2 to T1 only. There are no boarding facility at T2, only checkin, immigration and security facility.

Comment: I tried to get through transfer gate using my e-boarding pass(EBP), though they scanned the EBP they asked for the printed copy. So I approached my airline transfer desk and got a printed boarding pass without any issue. Once after entering the terminal 2 I cleared the security check and reached the gate using ground transportation(train).                                       As I don’t have check-in baggage I didn’t pass immigration at all.                                       hope this help others in similar situation.              Thank you all for your time and help rendered